# Journal requires to cite Arxiv pre-print of the same work – where and how do I cite?

Tags: citations, arxiv, self-plagiarism

I am submitting my paper to a journal that requires to cite Arxiv pre-prints within the content of the submitted article (presenting the same work) to avoid self-plagiarism. How would I practically perform such a citation:

- In which section of my manuscript should I cite the Arxiv reference?
- What would be an adequate explanation for this citation?

Comment: _a journal that requires to cite Arxiv pre-prints within the content of the submitted article (presenting the same work) to avoid self-plagiarism_ - I don't understand.  Are they asking for the arXiv id of the manuscript you're submitting or they want arXiv citations for references you use that are in the pre-print stage?

Comment: They want arxiv citation for references within the submitted manuscript with the proper explanation to avoid self-plagiarism case. As my article which has been submitted to the journal and its arxiv copy both have the same content, what would be the appropriate explanation for that?

Answer (score 15):

Add something like this to your "Introduction" section:

> This paper has been published as an arxiv pre-print<cite pre-print here>

This is the approach I used when I published part of the research I had done for my thesis. It conveys the necessary information without cluttering the paper with verbiage that a majority of readers will find irrelevant.

Answer (score 7):

In computer science, it's common for a short version of a paper to be published in conference proceedings, and then a full version in a journal. In that case, it's quite common to have a footnote to the title saying something like "A short version of this work appeared in *Proceedings of Awesome Conference 2018*, pp. 10–19. That Publishing Company, 2018." The same sort of thing would work for a preprint.